# Install pdflatex by installing texlive on Ubuntu from texlive site?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, ubuntu

I want to install `pdflatex`. It is in `texlive-latex-base` in my Ubuntu 14.04 repository. But I don't want to install `texlive-latex-base`, because Ubuntu repository usually has outdated software.

So I download `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`  from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html, and run `sudo ./install-tl`. After an hour and half, it finishes running.

- But I still don't have `pdflatex` when I run `pdflatex` in terminal. 
  Added: I found it is installed at `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`. Is it supposed to be there and not found when I run `pdflatex`?
- Does  `install-tl` install the same as `texlive-latex-base`?
- In order to install `pdflatex`, do I need to install `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` from Ubuntu repository?
- Can I keep the installed texlive by `install-tl`, and avoid installing the outdated texlive in `texlive-latex-base`?

Thanks.

Comment: Search the site for 'vanilla' and look down the results to the first one with many, many views/votes. There are instructions/scripts/stuff there for this.

Comment: I found pdflatex is installed at `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`. Is it supposed to be there and not found when I run `pdflatex`?

Comment: Just see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu. It is supposed to be there and it is supposed to be found when you say `pdflatex`.

Comment: (1) Yes but no. (2) No. (3) No. (4) Yes. See the linked question.

Comment: After you install it you have to add some path to the `$PATH`.